# Custom Index Update uses all the memory

Tags: index

I have a case on a sitecore project .

I have an import function which takes a folder structure from disk and transforms it in an items tree in sitecore. This executes with EventDisabler on because there a lot of items every time and we don't want that the index starts every time we create or we update an item. This works OK and it's quite fast

The problem appears after we finished the items creation we need to run an index update over that tree and we use this piece of code for this operation

```
Sitecore.ContentSearch.Maintenance.IndexCustodian.Refresh(ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("custom_index"), new SitecoreIndexableItem(StartItem))
```

The problem with this part is that it actually uses all the memory  (14Gb), the client becomes extremely slow and eventually the IIS app restarts.

This is Sitecore 8.2u7 hosted on Azure

I've been looking and trying a lot of stuff I found on blogs but nobody explains this issue because , probably, we used an wrong approach here.

It would be nice if anybody can explain what happens when we run this piece of code, why it uses so much memory and of course if there is a way to make it work.

It is important to run that Index update because in the same process , after the import is ready we have to do more processing , search items and continue updating them

Thank you

Comment: Have you try rebuilding instead of refresh ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30255139/difference-between-sitecore-solr-index-rebuild-and-refresh

Comment: Salut Alexandru, if you rebuild the index from index manager does it consume all memory  ?

Comment: @VladIobagiu - rebuild works fine, but the problem with this method is that I have like 300000 items in the index and it takes like 30mins, maybe more. During this period the content is not available .

Comment: If you are using SOLR, just make sure SwitchOnRebuildSolrSearchIndex is used for your index. Content will still be available if you rebuild.

Comment: This is a good solution. I've just found out about this SwitchOnRebuildSolrSearchIndex. I will give it a try, thank you @VincentLui Even if I didn't find out why that index update is using so much memory, this could be the solution to my problem :-)

Comment: Have you also experiment with IndexCustodian.PauseIndexing() and IndexCustodian.ResumeIndexing() ?

Comment: I've found a lot of caching issues with using EventDisabler. I think a better way is to use IndexCustodian.PauseIndexing() and IndexCustodian.ResumeIndexing().